# Bajar Scroll al maximo JQUERY

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

Tengo un formulario con filas determinadas y si doy click en el boton agregar se añade una nueva fila, el problema esta en que lo añade y el scroll se mantiene en la misma posicion; alguien sabe el codigo para bajar todo el scroll cada ves que de click en el boton agregar?

edit:

- Existe un div (#pie) al final del documento con un height de 60px para que el footer fixed no tape la pagina
- Eh intentado con esto:

  $("body").animate({scrollTop: $('#pie')[0].scrollHeight+1000}, 1000);
  y si funciona pero cuando bajo con la ruedita lo vuelve loco el scroll

[image: Foto]

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue :

```
$("body").animate({scrollTop: $('#pie')[0].scrollHeight+1000}, 1);
```